# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf' in google colab

Tags: rapids, cudf

I tried importing cudf and get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4d311da055f8> in <module>()
----> 1 import cudf; print('cuDF Version:', cudf.__version__)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of RAPIDS did you install?  What was the installation successful in the console print?

Comment: Did you run the first 2 cells on their notebook?

Comment: Worked after RAPIDS installation. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others, as this was solved through discussion in another channel, the cause of the issue was that there wasn't a RAPIDS compatible GPU connected to the Colab instance.

Just remember that the RAPIDS-Colab install script will check if you have a RAPIDS compatible GPU and let you know within the first 15 seconds.  Instead of erroring out, it will print out the issue and resolution steps, while NOT installing RAPIDS, as to not waste your time on something that won't work.

If you experience this issue, please check your print outs!